# Limit on Textarea Element when Posting Data

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using a plugin that one of my peers has developed internally that takes a HTML table and turns it into an excel file for exporting using `PHPExcel` & `simple_HTML_DOM`.

What happens is when called, it finds the table element, adds the html to a textarea and posts it to the PHP will which does the processing.

The issue is when we have a large amount of data in the table, it sends that content to the `textarea` element which seems to then break.

Here is the snippet of code that takes the HTML and adds it to a textarea:

```
var tableToExcel = {
download:function(html, fileName, fileExtension, autosizeToColumn){
    if(html && html!=""){
        if(!document.getElementById('tableToExcelForm')){
            var f = document.createElement('form');
            f.setAttribute('method', 'post');
            f.setAttribute('action', window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/resources/tableToExcel.php");
            f.setAttribute('id', 'tableToExcelForm');   
            f.style['display'] = "none";

            var t = document.createElement('textarea');
            t.setAttribute('name', 'table');
            t.setAttribute('id', 'tableToExcelTextarea');

         ......

            document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);
            document.getElementById('tableToExcelTextarea').value = html;
            document.getElementById('tableToExcelForm').submit();
```

If I pass the HTML to the PHP file directly, it works fine no matter the size so I know that's working fine. I believe it comes down to the amount of data a text area can hold even though its not implied in my code.

Is there another element that I can use to store this data before posting it to my PHP file?

Comment: Where is the problem? Client side or server side?

Comment: I'm thinking its client side. If I paste the same block of HTML into the php file this JS is passing it to, it works just fine. I believe that this textarea element is hitting some type of roof that I didn't know existed.

Comment: Uhm, it's still not clear if something breaks on the client application (errors from Chrome Inspector Console) or on the server application (PHP errors)

Comment: unless you have a `MAXLENGTH` attribute set on the text area, there really is no upper limit to a textarea. The limit would likely be more memory/browser dependent.

Comment: There is no maxlength set at all. Its a text area with a name and and ID; that's all.

Comment: How big is the table? Like length in characters. I would assume you wouldn't hit any browser/memory limit up to a few megs. Unless you have some sort of php setting blocking max post size.

Comment: When I paste it into a txt file and look it the size, its about 1.84MB in size.

Comment: My PHP post_max_size  is set to 2048M

Comment: AFAIK, there is no limit for a textarea (aside from browser/server post limits but those don't affect a textarea specifically and are usually above 1.8meg by default). Have you verified that the data being sent is complete (is it being cut off by client or server)? You can view the post through developer tools. You could try splitting the values up into several textareas if you think that is the issue.

Comment: Also, just an FYI, unless you tag someone like @SBB then they usually don't get a bump that you replied. OP gets bumped always and users typically only get bumped on their answers.